# How to solve(or numerically) a system of partial differential equation with mixed derivatives?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, systems-of-equations, partial-derivative

I have the following system of partial differential equation:
\begin{eqnarray}
a u_{z}f(u)uu_{z}-bu_{z}=u_{x}\\
f(u)uu_{z}=u_{y}
\end{eqnarray}
where $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ is a known constant,$u=u(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}$ an unknown scalar function and $f(u)\in\mathbb{R}$ a known scalar function.
$u_{x},u_{y},u_{z}$ are the partial deriviatives of function $u$

How can I solve or numerically solve this kind of equations?

Edit: Generalized the equations are
\begin{eqnarray}
a u_{z}F(u)-bu_{z}=u_{x}\\
F(u)u_{z}=u_{y}
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Since there is no special information about $f$, why bothering with $f(u) u$?

Comment: I want to keep the equation general, but in my problem the function f(u) has a specifc form

Comment: That's my point... If you want to consider general $f$, the $u$ term can be absorbed in the definition of $f$ and is therefore useless.

Comment: If you substitute $F(u) u_z = u_y$ in the first equation, you get an advection equation of the form
$$\vec{\omega} \cdot \nabla u = 0,$$
where $\vec{\omega} = (1,-a,b)$.

Answer (score 0):

$$uf(u)u_z-u_y=0$$
Charpit-Lagrange characteristic ODEs :
$$\frac{dz}{uf(u)}=\frac{dy}{1}=\frac{du}{0}$$
A first characteristic equation comes from $du=0$ :
$$u=c_1$$
A second characteristic equation comes from $\frac{dz}{c_1f(c_1)}=\frac{dy}{1}$ :
$$c_1f(c_1)z-y=c_2$$
The grneral solution on the form of implicit equation $c_1=F(c_2)$ is :
$$u=F\big(uf(u)z-y\big)$$
$F$ is an arbitrary function (to be determined according to some boundary conditions).

Without condition specified they are infinity many solutions since they are infinity many functions $F$ :
$$\boxed{u(x,y,z)=F\Big(u(x,y,z)f\big(u(x,y,z)\big)z-y\Big)} \tag 1$$

Without knowing explicitly the function $f$ one cannot expect to solve the implicit equation to get explicit $u(x,y,z)$.Even more if no boundary condition is specified in order to determine the function $F$.

Solving the other equation :
$$a u_{z}f(u)uu_{z}-bu_{z}=u_{x}$$
is much more arduous since this isn't a linear PDE. Even if it was possible for some particular function $f$ the general solution $u(x,y,z)$ would be generally not consistent with the above result $(1)$. This means that the solution of the whole problem ( with the two PDEs together) is made of two different functions $u(x,y,z)$ each one valid in a different volume both volumes separated by a surface border. This depends a lot of the conditions which should be specified in the wording of the problem.

Conclusion : The problem is far to be sufficiently specifically described to expect to find an analytic solution. Better rely on numerical solving. This supposes well specified boundary conditions and an explicit function $f$.